# Logical subscript too long in R

Tags: r

This might be a simple question, but can someone explain why the 3rd line of code below yields an error of "logical subscript too long"? And what is the difference between the 2nd and 3rd lines of code? Thanks!

```
try2 <- matrix(1 : 50, nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE)

try2[try2 < 10] <- 0

try2[try2 < 10,] <- 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `matrix` is just a `vector` with some dimensions as an attribute. I.e., `try2` is really just `1:50` with some extra details:

```
str(try2)
# int [1:10, 1:5] 1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46 ...
```

Similarly, a logical function applied against `try2` is just 50 TRUE or FALSE values, with some dimensions:

```
str(try2 < 10)
# logi [1:10, 1:5] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

Therefore

```
try2[try2 < 10] <- 0
```

is perfectly fine, as you have 50 values, indexed by 50 values. Everything matches up as expected.

On the other hand,

```
try2[try2 < 10,] <- 0
```

is asking for:

```
try2[rowselection, columnselection]
```

Unfortunately, you only have 10 rows, but you are trying to use an index of 50 values against these 10 rows. 50 is too long to fit into 10, therefore:

> Error in try2[try2 < 10, ] : (subscript) logical subscript too long

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! This is super helpful!